# how to play and upload RTSP protocol through Live Video Stream on Android

Tags: android

Hello i have one rtsp live video url, I have't know how to play this live stream live Video url.

i am working on android sample application. Please share your guide with me.

Following code using to play live streaming url. 
Don't have any idea, how to get live video streaming. Please suggest me any idea to send to live video stream to server.

below are my sample code.

```
public class MultimediaActivity extends Activity {
private static final String rtspURL = "rtsp://URL_IP:PORT+video+FileName";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
  Log.v("Video", "***Video to Play:: " + RTSP);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
  Uri video = Uri.parse(rtspURL);
  videoView.setMediaController(mc);
  videoView.setVideoURI(video);
  videoView.start();

}
}
```

please suggest me, What should i do..?

Thank you..

Comment: which format of video you trying to play flv,mp3,3gp etc?

Comment: play for mp4/flv video format.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for playing on player

> Intent i1 = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse(rtspURL));
>   startActivity(i1);

and use this code for videoview

> VideoView v1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
>           v1.setVideoPath(rtspURL); //your rtspurl
>   v1.start()

this work for me ...